# What is the operator precedence for the new C# 8.0 switch expressions?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, operator-precedence, c#-8.0, switch-expression

I just upgraded my current project to the newly released .NET Standard 2.1 and C# 8.0, and decided to convert some large `switch` statements into the new, much more compact [expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions).

Since the returned values are further used in some computations, I was wondering how the new `switch` expressions behave when the input variable is next to an operator.

Take the following example for string concatenation:

```cs
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string output = "Letter: " + input switch
{
    "1" => "a",
    "2" => "b",
    _ => "else"
};
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I guess that the `switch` binds very strongly to the `input` variable, and thus is evaluated first. And indeed, this prints `Letter: a`, when I type `1`.

But my question now is: **Does this behavior apply to any operator?**

From my experiments, I was not able to identify a condition where the above hypothesis does not hold, but that obviously does not mean that there isn't a case that I have missed. The docs also don't seem to mention operator precedence in context of `switch` expressions. Or do I have some deeper misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) doc now (possibly thanks to [@janw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528014/janw)) has the `switch` expression listed:

| Operators | Category or name |
| --- | --- |
| `x.y`, `f(x)`, `a[i]`, `x?.y`, `x?[y]`, `x++`, `x--`, `x!`, `new`, `typeof`, `checked`, `unchecked`, `default`, `nameof`, `delegate`, `sizeof`, `stackalloc`, `x->y` | Primary |
| `+x`, `-x`, `!x`, `~x`, `++x`, `--x`, `^x`, `(T)x`, `await`, `&x`, `*x`, `true` and `false` | Unary |
| `x..y` | Range |
| `switch`, `with` | `switch` and `with` expressions |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 5):

The Roslyn source suggests that indeed `switch` expressions have fairly high precedence, but there are some things with higher precedence such as ranges, unary operators, and casts. See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/4d749695a1aaa9558c72259d2c32df0a3fdff236/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/LanguageParser.cs#L8698) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/4d749695a1aaa9558c72259d2c32df0a3fdff236/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/LanguageParser.cs#L8724) in the Roslyn source.

Example code that demonstrates higher precedence of `SyntaxKind.LogicalNotExpression` (`Precende.Unary`):

```
var foo = false;
var bar = !foo switch {
    true => "true",
    false => "false"
};
Console.WriteLine(bar); // writes "true"
```

Comment: Nice find, didn't have the idea to check out Roslyn's sources directly. I will create an issue to include that into the docs :)